# Calling C5.0 in Python

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am attempting to call the c5.0 R function in Python using the rpy2 package. I am running into the following issue: C5.0 has a period in the function call, and this throws a Python error. Here is the code I have:

```
self.model = c50.C5.0(formula = formula, data = DataFrame(training_data))
```

This throws the error. Is there a way to call this C5.0 function in Python without throwing the error? Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on without a way to reproduce neither the full error message. I am guessing that you want to call the function `c50.C5_0()`.

Comment: If you were an experienced user of R you would have come across the fact that real R formulas are "language objects", so may not be successful if Python passes a character value to a formula object. This is far too little code to support much more thana WAG.

Answer (score 2):

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2 import robjects
C50 = importr('C50')    
C5_0 = robjects.r('C5.0')
```

Call the function by

```
C50.C5_0()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
C50.C5_0(x, y)
```

If you just pass the method a pd.dataframe for `x` and `y`, you will get a

```
RRuntimeError: Error: C5.0 models require a factor outcome
```

C5 accepts the dataframe for `x`, the error lies in the representation of `y`. To solve this

```
C50.C5_0(x, robjects.vectors.FactorVector(y))
```

rpy2 documentation:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/vector.html